# Get the closest path that have a config.rb file in file watcher plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

I recently installed the file watchers plugin, and I must configure it to use compass to compile my sass files.
My current config is:

```
Program: compass
Arguments: compile
Working dir: 
Env vars:
output:
```

How can I target the closest path to(upward folder tree) config.rb file within scss`s parents folders?
I need it to put in "Working dir:" field

My paths are

```
scss:
projects/<gitrepo>/<project>/<module-name>/static/<same-module-name>/scss/common/main.scss
css:
projects/<gitrepo>/<project>/<module-name>/static/<same-module-name>/css/common/main.css
config.rb are in:
projects/<gitrepo>/<project>/<module-name>
```

Module name and folders under scss may vary.

Thanks

Comment: not sure I follow you. Please can you provide more details on your configuration (project structure, sass/rb files location, config.rb settings)? Working dir should normally be the directory where your config.rb is located - you can just enter the full path there; arguments - smth like 'compile rb-file-folder $UnixSeparators($FilePath$)$'; output - the target directory name

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following solution:

1. Create a compass project in your Idea project folder by this command in your idea project folder:

   `compass create --css-dir <your css dir here> --sass-dir <your SASS dir here>`

   this will create a `config.rb` in the root of your idea project (this is important). You can learn more about possible options calling `compass create --help`.
2. Set up the following setting for SASS/SCSS file watcher

   ```
   Scope: project files 
   Program: compass.bat 
   Arguments: compile $FilePathRelativeToProjectRoot$ 
   Working directory: $ProjectFileDir$ 
   Environment variables: --empty--
   Output paths to refresh: --empty--
   ```
3. Please note that ruby bin folder is in my `PATH` environment variable.